# Limit of sum $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}}$

Tags: summation

I am having a hard time proving if this sum converges or diverges:

$$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}}$$

I tried proving it by the ratio test but $q = 1$.

I couldn’t proceed further and would like some help.

Comment: is $k=x$? $ $$ $$ $$ $

Comment: $\sqrt {k+1} \leq \sqrt {2k}$

Comment: @CalvinKhor sure, fixed

Comment: $\sqrt{x(x+1)}<x+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Dunno if it helps, but $\sqrt x<\sqrt {x+1}$ because the square root is increasing, and therefore

$$\frac1{\sqrt x\sqrt{x+1}}>\frac1{\sqrt {x+1}\sqrt {x+1}}=\frac1{x+1}$$

because $x\mapsto 1/x$ is decreasing for positive $x$.  Thus you are left with the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) (minus 1).

Comment: So you can show that $$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x+1} < \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}} < \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} $$

Comment: @kronenbouh Yes, but the left-hand inequality is enough because the harmonic series grows beyond all positive bounds.

Comment: @kronenbouh ...and the $<$ turns into a $\leqslant$ in the limit.

Comment: Ok, then the problem is solved, the series is divergent